# How do I prevent Odoo from creating __pycache__ directories in custom module directories?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo

I've tried launching Odoo with `python3 -B /usr/bin/odoo` instead of just running `/usr/bin/odoo`, but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

The `__pycache__` directories are irritating because when I switch branches in my Git repository for my custom modules, module directories that don't exist on the branch I'm checking out end up hanging around because of the presence of the ignored `__pycache__` directories.

Comment: Seems like you shouldn't disable pychaches, but rather put it in your .gitignore file.

Comment: in your .gitignore add this *__pycache__/*

Comment: This is not the solution. I already have `__pycache__` in my `.gitignore` file. They are not getting added to the repo. However, their presence causes directories they are in to hang around when switching branches because when you switch branches Git rightfully won't just remove untracked files. This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code at the top of your file

```
import sys
sys.dont_write_bytecode = True
```

Comment: Wouldn't this do exactly the same thing as running the file with the `-B` flag?